# How to solve error: Unhandled Rejection during a dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I am trying to set a `redux` store, which is the first time and I learn by doing, and I am finding it a bit hard due to a lot of moving parts. 
I get an error saying:

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Given action "GET_ERRORS", reducer "errors" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined.

I will show the code that is highlighted during the problem:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_ERRORS } from './types';


const createProject = (project, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/project', project);

    history.push('/dashboard');
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ERRORS,
      payload: err.response,
    });
    return null;
  }
};
export default createProject;
```

The api post call is working but then still it crashed and gives the above error

Comment: any info needed will be provided

Comment: Can you add your reducer?

Comment: import { GET_ERRORS } from '../Actions/types';

const initialState = {};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ERRORS:
      return action.payload;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

Comment: Can you console.log(err.response) in the first line in catch block? it seems undefined, can you confirm?

Comment: It does show an error, if its a 400 bad request etc kind of error it clearly shows

Comment: So it is defined

Answer (score 1):

Your payload is not getting any error message.
Edit your payload line like this:

```
payload: error.response.data,
```

And also remember to remove your `return null;`.